# How can i solve C when function f(x) is continuous

Tags: limits

How can i solve this

Specify the constant c so that the function $f(x)$ is continually continuous.

Function $f(x)$ is defined as follows:

$f(x)={-x^2+c , x \le 8}$
and $f(x)={x-7c, x \ge 8}$

like this is solved:

$f(x)={b*x-9 , x \le 3}$ --> 3*b-9
and $f(x)={x^2-3, x \ge 3}$ --> $3^3-3=6$

and then $3*b-9=6$ so b is 5

How can i solve upper like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "continually continuous"?

Comment: What does "continually continuous" mean?

Comment: It's worth noting that since $8$ is not in the domain of $f$, this is a continuous function for any $c$ (it's a bit different if we have a $\leq$ or $\geq$ somehere in the piecewise definition). But maybe that's the 'continually' part: That the domain is connected.

Comment: i just edited this and Roland is right so it's continuous function for any c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this function is clearly continuous (since its a polynomial!) for every point $x\neq 8$. To find $c$ so that it becomes continuous at $x = 8$, you want the left and right limits of the function
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-x^2+c, & x \leq 8\\
x-7c, & x > 8
\end{cases}\, ,
$$
when $x\to 8^{\pm}$ to be equal. The left limit is

$$
\lim_{x\to 8^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 8^-} -x^2+c = -64+c\, ,
$$
and the right limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to 8^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 8^+} x-7c = 8-7c\, .
$$

Equate and solve for $c$ to get $c = 9$.

**Notational remark:**
When I write $x\to 8^-$ I mean precisely that $x < 8$, but tends to $8$. It tends to 8 *from the left* or *from below*. Another common notation for this is $x \nearrow 8$.

Conversely, $x\to 8^+$ means that $x > 8$ but tends to $8$. One says that $x$ tends to 8 *from the right* or *from above*. The notation $x \searrow 8$ is sometimes used here.

Comment: Is it same if the lower is $x\ge8$

Comment: In practice (in regards of calculations), then yes, its the same. 

Technically I wanted to put strict inequality on either, because otherwise $f$ is not a *function* if $c\neq 9$ since it would take 2 different values at $x = 8$. 

As an example to illustrate what I mean, let $c = 0$. Then if we would have $f(x) = \begin{cases}-x^2, & x \leq 8 \\ x, & x \geq 8\end{cases}$, (note the non-strict inequality in both places) what would $f(8)$ be?

Comment: i think you calculated that -16 that 8*2? When it should be $8^2=-64$ is that right?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. You're right. :-) I edited my answer.

Comment: Is there any other solutions than c=9 if the question says "for all real numbers"?

Comment: No. Although I'm not sure what you're saying (where and in what context does it say "for all real numbers"?), there is not many other interpretations of the exercise.

Comment: ok. thanks! this will do and i am grateful.